# Is it possible to upgrade the OS of Windows Mobile?

Tags: upgrade, operating-systems, windows-mobile

Currently I am using htc with Windows Mobile 6. So, is it possible to upgrade it to Windows Mobile 6.1 or new WM 6.5? If yes, please provide link to the articles related to this issue.

Comment: Do note that your phone has to be "good" enough to handle the new Rom, since either performance may be poor or you don't have the correct drivers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend [**XDA-developers**](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=313) because it's focused on HTC phones and offers choice between different types of ROMS. You can upgrade from WinMo 6 to 6.1 or 6.5, but the newer ROMs require more RAM and possibly faster processors, so performance isn't guaranteed on older types.

Note that this will probably void your warranty, but especially if it's an older phone I wouldn't worry about that too much. Also note that you should follow the guides as good as possible in the beginning, because else you might "brick" your phone. Off course that's often fixable, but it sure ain't fun.

[This Wiki page](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=359) refers you to all the available ROMs for your type of phone and probably also has a guide on how to do it.

Comment: i agree with you. there is lot of risk in that. i am researching more on the issue and about the side effects. thanks.

Comment: Well risks... You can always download and reinstall the original ROM, which should restore everything back to normal. The biggest problem is that it can be time consuming and frustrating if your stuck and you don't have a  full tutorial explaining what to do. I think XDA supplies everything you need, but it does take some research

Comment: yes. xda is awesome. still couldn't reach conclusion whether go ahead or not..

Comment: If you post your model number, we can find something more specific ;-)

Comment: its htc p3400i frm India. purchased around 7-8 months ago

Comment: Updated the link to refer to HTC Trinity

Answer (score 1):

HTC will often provide the upgrades free of charge for devices that support them. This can be done through the HTC website. However, this is rare  since a lot of the Mobile devices are developed for a particular OS. I did this in the past on the older Windows 5 Mobiles, but since I got my iPhone I have not kept up to date.

Comment: The iphone sure did make phone system updates easy in comparison to everything out there.

Comment: i checked htc site but there is no upgrade for my phone.

Comment: Good luck if you have a branded/OEM HTC phone then ;-)

Comment: If it is not available from HTC and not a branded phone it is possibly not supported and Ivo solution is the only on that might work.

Answer (score 0):

Sprint made available a WM6.1 update for their Mogul, made by HTC. It installed easily, but I was glad I did it right after purchase because the result was a brand new phone except for the service setup. I haven't gone looking for anything newer because (despite rumors to the contrary) I really am in the "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" camp for devices I actually depend on day to day.